# Windows Driver Kit Cannot Open ddk/ntddk.h

Tags: wdk

So im currently trying to make a driver.
And when i add:

```
#include <ddk/ntddk.h>
```

I get the error: Cannot open source file "ddk/ntddk.h". How do i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of the WDK are you using?

For WDK 8 and above, there is no directory called ddk shipped by the WDK, so the include that you have wouldn't work... Just look at where exactly on your disk is ntddk.h located, and make sure that the additional include directories specified in the compiler options include whichever location has ntddk.h. By default, in WDK 8 and above, it should be (and thus you don't need a *ddk/* prefix).